# Difference between int plus plus and int plus equals 1

Tags: ios, objective-c

So I'm trying to fill an object with rows from my sqlite database like so:

```
- (id) initWithSQLite:(sqlite3_stmt *)row andDatabase:(Database*)db
{
   self.valueX = sqlite3_column_int(row, 0);
   self.valueY = sqlite3_column_int(row, 1);
   self.valueZ = sqlite3_column_int(row, 2);
   //etc
   return self;
}
```

Since there are a lot of properties and more properties are being added after database migrations, I tried to be a smart ass and change the code to:

```
- (id) initWithSQLite:(sqlite3_stmt *)row andDatabase:(Database*)db
{
   int i = 0;
   self.valueX = sqlite3_column_int(row, i);
   self.valueY = sqlite3_column_int(row, i++);
   self.valueZ = sqlite3_column_int(row, i++);
   //etc
   return self;
}
```

Yet this doesn't work, but if I change it to `sqlite3_column_int(row, i+=1);` it does seem to work.

So my question is: What is the difference between `i++` and `i += 1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out!
It seems that `i++` first returns the current value of `i` and only then adds 1 to it. While `i+=1` first adds the number and only then returns the value of `i`. So if I simply change the code to this, all works fine:

```
- (id) initWithSQLite:(sqlite3_stmt *)row andDatabase:(Database*)db
{
   int i = 0;

   //i++ instead of i, 0 is the returned value here and not 1 as I expected:
   self.valueX = sqlite3_column_int(row, i++); 

   self.valueY = sqlite3_column_int(row, i++);
   self.valueZ = sqlite3_column_int(row, i++);
   //etc
   return self;
}
```

I hope I'll save someone some time with this

Answer (score 3):

`i++` is postfix notation, here `i` is incremented only after the statement is executed.

While `i+=1` expands to `i = i+1`, here `i` is incremented on the same statement. You can also achieve this with prefix notation by `++i`.

Answer (score 2):

`i += 1;` is just a short-hand for `i = i + 1;`

`i++` is called a post-increment. It returns the value of `i` within the expression and then increments it. Its counterpart is `++i`, which is called a pre-increment. It increments `i` within the expression.